# Report Builder 2016 Install Error .NET Framework 4.5 not found

Tags: reporting-services, .net-4.5

Has anyone encountered this issue with installing SQL Server 2016 Report Builder?

I am stuck in a loop of not being able to install because .NET Framework 4.5 is not being detected on my system, but the installer for .NET 4.5 says that it is installed on my system.

[image: Install Errors for Report Builder 2016]

Answer (score 7):

A simpler and more direct way to get this done is to:

1. Run a CMD window as Administrator
2. Navigate to your download folder, or wherever you have the ReportBuilder3.msi file
3. run the following command: msiexec /i ReportBuilder3.msi

The installer should run successfully without having to mess with your registry.

Answer (score 0):

The root of the issue is, the package needed to install as an Administrator.
I tried running the .msi file from an admin command prompt, and that did not work at first.  So I needed to modify my registry, and to give me the ability to install the .msi file as an Admin from the GUI.

[Registry changes to run a .msi file as admin from GUI](https://www.howtogeek.com/178826/how-to-force-an-msi-package-to-install-using-administrator-mode/)